# Awk to print only matching word

Tags: shell-script, awk

I need to create a script that will produce a Makefile.

When checking for dependencies, I check each .cpp file for their "---.h" header. I use:

```
echo $(awk '/^".*h"$/ { print $0 }' $file) >> Makefile
```

What is the best way to just get the 'myheader.h' part, exluding ' ', obviously. Can I achieve this with awk? Preferably, the simpler the better. I barely, at this point, understand awk.

UPDATE:

The following solved my problem:

```
awk -F '"' '/\.h"/ {print $2}' $file
```

Comment: That's a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) unless you specifically require the shell to tokenize the output from Awk on whitespace and expand any wildcards.

Comment: Have you had a look at `gcc -M`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why `awk`? for this?  `grep -EPo '[^\s]+\.h[\s]' /path/to/src/*.cpp >> Makefile` should do the trick.

Comment: The `\s` Perl escape code isn't generally supported by plain `grep`.  If you have `grep -P` you can use that (i.e. `-P -o`) or replace `\s` with the POSIX character class `[:space:]`.  Also, in the absence of `-P` or `-E`, the `+` repetition operator needs to be backslashed in POSIX `grep`.

Comment: @triplee, `\s` is now supported by GNU `grep` but not inside `[...]` as that would break POSIX compliance (`[\s]` is meant to match either backslash or `s`).

Answer (score 2):

The posted (and currently accepted) `grep` answer has a number of issues, not the least of which is that *any* string which contains the sequence `.h` will be printed, not just the ones matched in the regex in the Awk script (so for example, from a structure member reference like `linkedlist.head`).  I would use `sed` for this:

```
sed -n 's/^"\(.*h\)"$/\1/p "$file" >> Makefile
```

I have a strong suspicion that the OP doesn't *actually* want to match any string which ends with the letter `h` in double quotes, which is what this regular expression actually does.  Perhaps a more reasonable guess would be something like

```
sed -n 's/^ *# *include  *"\([^"]*\.h\)".*$/\1/p < "$file" >> Makefile
```

The `#include` with optional whitespace before it is an educated guess.  The beef here is the regular expression `[^"]*\.h` which captures a string which contains no double quotes and ends with the literal characters `.h`.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`, you could use:

```
awk -F '"' '
  /^[[:blank:]]*#[[:blank:]]*include[[:blank:]]+".*\.h"/ {
    print $2
  }'
```

We set the field separator to `"`, match for lines that look like

```
#include "something.h"
```

And from them, extract the second field (so what's between the first  and second `"`).